# Swift / SwiftNIO / Vapor: wait() or similar inside EventLoop & equivalent to JavaScript‘s Promise.all()

Tags: swift, vapor, swift-nio

I‘m starting with Vapor 4 and got stuck at the very beginning of my journey.

I know Promises in JavaScript and I think I have an understanding of Swift‘s Futures. I think my problem is the fact, that sadly most tutorials out there use `wait()` to keep their examples short and simple. In Vapor I‘m confronted with the EventLoop and `wait()` being forbidden in there.

#### What I‘m trying to do

I’m trying to perform some queries on a MySQL database, which need to be executed serially:

1. Two tables are truncated.
2. *Then* I'm copying all rows from a third table into one of the truncated tables.
3. *Finally* I'm querying that filled table, try to iterate over each matched result and insert it into the other one of the truncated tables.

#### What's going wrong / where I need help

1. After some days of hard to understand compile errors it's now running. The first part is being executed but it's missing a correct implementation of some callback. I'm thinking of something like [Promise.all([])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in JavaScript. I don't want to nest these two queries because I think it's cleaner to have an array of table names and executing the query for each of them. That's the first minor thing I don't know how to do.
2. **Most importantly:** the second step, **inserting the matched rows into the other table, fails**. In the console in Xcode it prints many times:
   `[ ERROR ] Connection request timed out. This might indicate a connection deadlock in your application. If you're running long running requests, consider increasing your connection timeout. [database-id: mysql, request-id: F159E838-0E90-4025-929E-596A6A66A502]`

I guess there are a couple of better ways to solve this problem, but because I want to learn and thinking of some other tasks I'd like to try to implement I would like to solve it by executing these queries serially.

#### My code

**`Controllers/RubricsTreeController.swift`**

```swift
import Fluent
import FluentMySQLDriver
import MySQLNIO
import Vapor

struct RubricsTreeController: RouteCollection {
    func rebuild(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Rubric]> {
        let mysql = req.db as? MySQLDatabase

        // Clear database tables
        let tables = ["rubrics", "rubrics_tree"]
        for table in tables {
            mysql!.simpleQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE `\(table)`")    // <-- HERE …
            // … I´d like to somehow collect each returned Future in an Array …
        }
        // … and wait for all Futures to finish

        // Copy contents from imported `import` into table `rubrics`
        mysql!.simpleQuery("INSERT INTO `rubrics` SELECT * FROM `import`")

        // Iterate over all Rubrics and build the Tree by inserting each as a Node into the Nested Set
        let nestedSet = NestedSet(database: mysql!, table: "rubrics_tree")
        var nestedSetRootId = 1;
        let rubrics = Rubric.query(on: mysql as! Database)
            .filter(\.$level == 0)
            .sort(\.$level)
            .sort(\.$parentId)
            .sort(\.$sorting)
            .sort(\.$id)
            .all()
            .flatMapEachThrowing { rubric -> Rubric in
                try? nestedSet.newRoot(rootId: UInt16(nestedSetRootId), foreignId: UInt64(rubric.id!))
                nestedSetRootId += 1
                return rubric
            }
        return rubrics
    }
}
```

**`Helpers/NestedSet.swift`**

```swift
import Fluent
import FluentMySQLDriver
import Vapor

class NestedSet {
    var database: MySQLDatabase
    var table: String

    init(database: MySQLDatabase, table: String) {
        self.database = database
        self.table = table
    }

    func newRoot(id: UUID? = nil, rootId: UInt16, foreignId: UInt64? = nil) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Bool> {
        return database
            .simpleQuery("INSERT INTO `\(table)`(rootId, leftValue, rightValue, nodeLevel, nodeMoved, foreignId) VALUES(\(rootId), 1, 2, 0, 0, \(foreignId ?? 0)")
            .map { _ -> Bool in
                true
            }
    }

//  func newRoot(id: UUID? = nil, foreignId: UInt64? = nil) throws -> EventLoopFuture<EventLoopFuture<Bool>> {
//      return database
//          .simpleQuery("SELECT COALESCE(MAX(rootId), 0) AS highestRootId FROM `\(table)`")
//          .flatMapThrowing { (results: [MySQLRow]) in
//              let highestRootId = (results[0].column("highestRootId")?.uint64)!
//              let rootId = UInt16(highestRootId + 1)
//              return try self.newRoot(id: id, rootId: rootId, foreignId: foreignId)
//          }
//  }
}
```

I'm curious about your ideas and improvements! :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to use the new async/await stuff if you can. This will make the code much easier to write.

However, to do this in `EventLoopFuture` land, you can use `flatten` to convert an array of futures to a future array. E.g.

```swift
struct RubricsTreeController: RouteCollection {
    func rebuild(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Rubric]> {
        let mysql = req.db as? MySQLDatabase

        // Clear database tables
        let tables = ["rubrics", "rubrics_tree"]
        var truncateResults = [EventLoopFuture<Void>]()
        for table in tables {
            let future = mysql!.simpleQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE `\(table)`").transform(to: ())
            truncateResults.append(future)    
        }
        // … and wait for all Futures to finish
        return truncateResults.flatten(on: req.eventLoop).flatMap {

            // Copy contents from imported `import` into table `rubrics`
            return mysql!.simpleQuery("INSERT INTO `rubrics` SELECT * FROM `import`").flatMap { _ in

                // Iterate over all Rubrics and build the Tree by inserting each as a Node into the Nested Set
                let nestedSet = NestedSet(database: mysql!, table: "rubrics_tree")
                var nestedSetRootId = 1;
                let rubrics = Rubric.query(on: mysql as! Database)
                    .filter(\.$level == 0)
                    .sort(\.$level)
                    .sort(\.$parentId)
                    .sort(\.$sorting)
                    .sort(\.$id)
                    .all()
                    .flatMapEachThrowing { rubric -> Rubric in
                        try? nestedSet.newRoot(rootId: UInt16(nestedSetRootId), foreignId: UInt64(rubric.id!))
                        nestedSetRootId += 1
                        return rubric
                    }
                return rubrics
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `mysql!.simpleQuery` returns a `Future` you could collect the Futures into an array as

```
    let tables = ["rubrics", "rubrics_tree"]
    let futuresArray = tables.map { aTable in 
        mysql!.simpleQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE `\(aTable)`")
    }
```

To my knowledge there is nothing in `Combine` like `Promise.all()` but there is a community supported library called [CombineExt](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt) that has [ZipMany](https://github.com/CombineCommunity/CombineExt#zipmany) which looks like what you're looking for.